# Creating a settings table in Mysql and fetching with eloquent in laravel

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I want to create a settings table with 2 columns (Setting, value) and setting will hold something like SITE_NAME and Value will be the value like "Facebook" or "Youtube" or something like that. This will hold the site name, logo url and etc. How would i create this and most importantly how would i fetch the info with Laravel eloquent without a id field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first.

Your table requires a `primary key`. Will that be a `varchar` field, according to your example? MySql's search by name is **WAY SLOWER** than comparing an with an index (integer). What it does in theory (google can explain it better) is somewhat converting text to an index and validating it, whereas with an index it just accesses it. I see nothing wrong - infact, I support - the idea of having an `id` column as a primary key. If duplicates is your worry, then you can set unique on your column `site_name`.

1. Create a migration to create a table

   ```
   php artisan make:migration settings_table
   ```
2. Fill your migration code

   ```
   <?php

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
   use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

   class SettingsTable extends Migration
   {
       /**
        * Run the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function up()
       {
           Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
               //$table->increments('id'); This will come in hand, trust me
               $table->string('site_name',255)->unique();
               //If you really insist on having site_name as primary key, then use the line below
               // $table->string('site_name',255)->primary();
               $table->string('value',255);
               //$table->timestamps(); Do you need?
           });
       }

       /**
        * Reverse the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function down()
       {
           Schema::dropIfExists('settings');
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a Eloquent model

   ```
   php artisan make:model Setting
   ```
4. Fill your Eloquent model

   ```
   namespace App\Models;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class Setting extends Model
   {
       protected $fillable = ['site_name','value'];
       //protected $table = ['settings'] Only if you really need it
       //Usually, if you take Laravel's approach, Models are singular version of the tables, that are in plural, but you can work it as you like
   }
   ```